# Enable correct permissions to allow a SQL Server database account to bulk insert through a stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I have a stored procedure which I am trying to call from a command line vb.net program running on SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE #ftpData(ftp_Email varchar(150) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, ftp_Segment varchar(1) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
BULK INSERT #ftpData FROM 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\tempSegFiles\segmentation_.csv'
WITH(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

When I run this from management studio it executes successfully. When I call the stored procedure from my vb.net program I get the error

> *Cannot bulk load because the file "xxx" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.)*

The SQL account that I log in with to call the stored procedure has permissions for altering, executing, inserting and administer bulk operations. It also has server wide security privileges to bulkadmin, diskadmin, public.

Are there any other options that are required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Access is denied" error indicates the problem is with accessing the CSV file you're trying to bulk insert. Make sure that whatever account is executing the command line (and the stored procedure) also has permissions to read the CSV file.

UPDATE: I see you're using a SQL login to run the procedure. Please see the section titled "Security Considerations" at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx). To wit:

> If a user uses a SQL Server login, the security profile of the SQL
>   Server process account is used.